# Raspberry PI can't open camera index

Tags: python

I take the camera from the outside
It is possible to turn the camera on and off using Python.
Often, however, in the process of turning the same camera on and off [WARN:0@40.938] global /tmp/pip-wheel-efxaz4j7/opencv-python_bedc0fac27944da0021e079da44d32bf/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO (V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index is alerted and the camera does not open.
Could you ever solve these problems? It's not that it doesn't open every time, it's that it doesn't open every once in a while.

```
while True:
    all_state=0
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Camera open1 failed")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            print("camera open2 failed")
    
    state_bat, igw, igh = cam_read(cap, ser_grbl)
    print('state_bat = ', state_bat, igw, igh)
    if (state_bat ==0):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        cam_state=servo_AT(servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin, ser_grbl, igw, igh)
        print('cam_state =', cam_state)

        if(cam_state==0):

            move_pickup(ser_grbl, -8, -168)
            servo_DT(servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
            move_pickup(ser_grbl, -8, -190)
            #time.sleep(0.1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
            if not cap2.isOpened():
                print("Camera2 open failed")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
                if not cap2.isOpened():
                    print("Camera2 open2 failed")
                    all_state=1
            if(all_state==0):
                bat_scan(cap2, ser_grbl, servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin)
                cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
                if not cap3.isOpened():
                    print("Camera3 open failed")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
                    if not cap3.isOpened():
                        print("Camera3 open3 failed")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                double_state = bat_scan2(cap3, ser_grbl, servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
                print('double_state = ', double_state)
                if (double_state==0):
                    bat_down(servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
                    servo_DT(servo1_pin,  servo2_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    servo_INIT(servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin)
                else:
                    move_pickup(ser_grbl, -42, -195.7)
                    bat_down(servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.3)
                    servo_DT(servo1_pin,  servo2_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    servo_INIT(servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
                    if not cap2.isOpened():
                        print("Camera2 open failed")
                    bat_scan(cap2, ser_grbl, servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    bat_down(servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.3)
                    servo_DT(servo1_pin,  servo2_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    servo_INIT(servo1_pin, servo2_pin, sensor_pin)
                    time.sleep(0.3)
            #bat_down(servo1_pin, servo2_pin)
                #time.sleep(0.2)
           else:
                homing(ser_grbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got same error on windows. i solved the problem with this command. Command is only for PC not Raspberry PI

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

also you can use -1 instead of 0 to solve the problem

```
cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

I cant see cap.release() in your code. you should use cap1.release() before open cap2 ( or cap2.release() before open cap1 ) if you dont use both camera. this command will close the video1 source. if u use both camera simultaniously, raspberry pi's band with may not allow to open two cameras.

Comment: I'm using two cameras. Can both cameras apply DSHOW?

Comment: Currently the camera index numbers are using -1 and 2 respectively

Comment: yes you can apply both of them.

Comment: Applying what you have said, cv2. VideoCapture(-1, DSHOW) and cv2. When I applied VideoCapture(2, DSHOW) and ran it, the camera failed to open. I use the Raspberry Pi and the language uses Python.

Comment: getting any error message ? could you please share?

Comment: if you used dshow no error message was displayed just the camera failed to open

Comment: can you share your code ? or some part of about camera?

Comment: The source code is long, so I'll leave it as an answer

Comment: you should add it to your post, not an answer. edit your post.

Comment: I've made corrections to the post.

Comment: i checked your code. u should use cap1.release() before open cap2 ( or cap2.release() before open cap1 ) if you dont use both camera. this command will close the video1 source. if u use both camera simultaniously, raspberry pi's band with may not allow to open two cameras.

Comment: Warning DSHOW is for pc not raspberry pi

Comment: For 2 camera  use this cv2.VideoCapture(1). 0 mean 1 camera, 1 mean 2 cameras and so. on

Comment: If you have 2 camera then use this cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) instead of cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2) <=== that 3 camera

Comment: The cam_read() and bat_scan() functions contain cap.release() and cv2.destroyAllwindows(), respectively. Even though I exited via release, when I reopen and close it, I often get an error stating that the camera index number is incorrect.

Comment: cv2. The reason I didn't use VideoCapture(0) and (1) is that I am using -1 and 2 because the respective index numbers are incorrect.